# Como reproducir multiples efectos en python al mismo tiempo ? (pygame)

Tags: python

-Actualmente estoy terminando un juego de terminal con `Python`, no use nada de `PyGame` (principalmente por que no lo conozco muy a fondo) a excepcion del `mixer` para el tema de los sonidos, sin embargo, al ser un programa que corre en la terminal, el unico modo que tengo de emular movimiento es borrando la pantalla constantemente (si hay alguna otra forma, que no sea el emplep de la libreria `curses`, por favor mencionar), por otro lado, los sonidos se 'superponen' (es decir, cuando ejecuto uno cuando otro se esta ejecutando este ultimo es el que se ejecuta, poniendo al primero en una especie de `call stack` ) constantemente, y se escucha muy mal, con lo cual la pregunta seria: hay algun modo de ejecutar muchos efectos a la vez sin que se 'superpongan'.

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.Sound(file).play()
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código completo de tu juego por favor?

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta, por eso te pido el código completo. Pero si es lo que pienso, puedes usar pygame.mixer.stop() para parar todos los sonidos que actualmente se ejecutan antes de reproducir el nuevo sonido.

Comment: O lo que quieres es poner a los sonidos en una especie de lista de espera?

Comment: Por que de principio es contradictorio. Como ejecutas muchos sonidos a la vez sin que se superpongan? Es logicamente imposible, asi que algo no estoy entendiendo.

Comment: @DanteS. Te pondria el codigo, solamente que tiene varias dependencias que no vas a poder conseguir (ya que estan hechas por mi) pero la idea es esa, reproducir varios sonidos a la vez